# Game of bullets

Tags: probability, combinatorics, average

Lets say with have a game with 10 targets. In each turn the participant shoots X number of different and random targets, where X is a random whole number between 0 and 10 (included). Game ends when all targets were shot atleast once.

My question is: would the average amount of turns it takes to complete such game would change if the participant shoots exactly 5 (the everage of X) targets every turn? Why?

Clarification: Targets can be shot more than once.

Comment: What is the strategy of the shooter?  Does the shooter have a criterion _for winning_ or just shoots randomly?  Marksmanship counts?

Comment: No strategy, he shoots randomly and hits his target 100% of the time.

Comment: He shoots randomly inside each turn?

Comment: X random targets, yes. With the only restriction that he does not shoot the same target twice in the same turn.

Answer (score 1):

Let $L_t$ be the number of targets unshot after $t$ turns. We have $L_0=10$ and $0 \le L_t \le L_{t-1}$.  If $X_t$ is the number of targets of the $10$ original targets aimed for in turn $t$ then we also have $L_{t-1}-X_t \le L_t \le 10-X_t$.

Then using the hypergeometric distribution $$\Pr(L_t=a|L_{t-1}=b, X_t=x) = \frac{{b \choose b-a}{10-b \choose x-b+a}}{{10 \choose x}}$$ which means $$\Pr(L_t=a|L_{t-1}=b) = {\sum_x}  \Pr (X_t=x) \frac{{b \choose b-a}{10-b \choose x-b+a}}{{10 \choose x}}.$$

In your (a) $\Pr (X_t=x) = \frac{1}{11}$ for $0 \le x \le 10$, while in your (b) $\Pr (X_t=5) = 1$. So we can constrict Markov chain transition matrices, and then take powers.

My calculated probabilities for finishing on particular turns are shown below: in particular note that with (a) random $X$ the probability of finishing on the first turn  is $\frac1{11}$, while with (b) fixed $X=5$ the probability of finishing on the first turn is $0$ while the probability of finishing on the second turn  is $\frac{1}{252}$.  So it should not be implausible that the expected number of turns for (a) of about $3.928968$ is smaller than the expected number of turns for (b) of about $4.933981$.

```
   Turns  (a)randomX  (b)fixedX
 [1,]  1 9.090909e-02 0.000000e+00
 [2,]  2 1.836252e-01 3.968254e-03
 [3,]  3 2.108153e-01 1.732332e-01
 [4,]  4 1.821052e-01 3.018183e-01
 [5,]  5 1.323364e-01 2.323861e-01
 [6,]  6 8.583148e-02 1.377232e-01
 [7,]  7 5.149821e-02 7.394685e-02
 [8,]  8 2.926200e-02 3.812891e-02
 [9,]  9 1.600121e-02 1.932336e-02
[10,] 10 8.515839e-03 9.719392e-03
[11,] 11 4.446310e-03 4.872535e-03
[12,] 12 2.290571e-03 2.439122e-03
[13,] 13 1.169014e-03 1.220196e-03
[14,] 14 5.927527e-04 6.102388e-04
[15,] 15 2.992137e-04 3.051507e-04
[16,] 16 1.505759e-04 1.525823e-04
[17,] 17 7.561695e-05 7.629271e-05
[18,] 18 3.791970e-05 3.814670e-05
[19,] 19 1.899732e-05 1.907343e-05
[20,] 20 9.511250e-06 9.536730e-06
[21,] 21 4.759848e-06 4.768369e-06
[22,] 22 2.381338e-06 2.384185e-06
[23,] 23 1.191142e-06 1.192093e-06
[24,] 24 5.957290e-07 5.960464e-07
[25,] 25 2.979173e-07 2.980232e-07
[26,] 26 1.489763e-07 1.490116e-07
[27,] 27 7.449402e-08 7.450581e-08
[28,] 28 3.724897e-08 3.725290e-08
[29,] 29 1.862514e-08 1.862645e-08
[30,] 30 9.312789e-09 9.313226e-09
[31,] 31 4.656467e-09 4.656613e-09
[32,] 32 2.328258e-09 2.328306e-09
[33,] 33 1.164137e-09 1.164153e-09
[34,] 34 5.820712e-10 5.820766e-10
[35,] 35 2.910366e-10 2.910383e-10
[36,] 36 1.455184e-10 1.455192e-10
[37,] 37 7.275947e-11 7.275958e-11
[38,] 38 3.637979e-11 3.637968e-11
[39,] 39 1.818978e-11 1.819001e-11
[40,] 40 9.094947e-12 9.094947e-12
[41,] 41 4.547474e-12 4.547474e-12
[42,] 42 2.273848e-12 2.273737e-12
[43,] 43 1.136646e-12 1.136868e-12
[44,] 44 5.684342e-13 5.683232e-13
[45,] 45 2.842171e-13 2.843281e-13
[46,] 46 1.421085e-13 1.421085e-13
[47,] 47 7.116530e-14 7.105427e-14
[48,] 48 3.552714e-14 3.552714e-14
[49,] 49 1.776357e-14 1.776357e-14
[50,] 50 8.881784e-15 8.770762e-15
[51,] 51 4.440892e-15 4.551914e-15
[52,] 52 2.331468e-15 2.220446e-15
[53,] 53 8.881784e-16 1.110223e-15
[54,] 54 5.551115e-16 5.551115e-16
[55,] 55 4.440892e-16 2.220446e-16
[56,] 56 3.330669e-16 1.110223e-16
[57,] 57 0.000000e+00 1.110223e-16
[58,] 58 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00
```